# Capybara: Helper Macros, Toggling Between app_host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I've created a 'lil helper file to DRY up my specs:

```
module RemoteMacros

  def go_to_another_localhost(port)

    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
    Capybara.app_host = "localhost:#{port}"
    Capybara.run_server = false

  end

  def go_webapp

    Capybara.current_driver = :rack_test
    Capybara.app_host = "localhost:3000"
    Capybara.run_server = true

  end

end
```

And here's the spec that goes with it:

```
require "rails_helper"

describe "Placing an ad", :type => :feature do

  it "(1) The ad token should match across domains" do
    go_to_another_localhost(8000)
    visit "/"
    expect(page).to have_css( 'iframe[data-nc-token="demo-token"]' )
  end

  it "(2) can go places" do
    go_webapp
    visit "/"
    save_and_open_page
    expect(page).to have_content( 'lol' )
  end

end
```

At first glance, it seems as though everything should work as expected (how many times has THAT been said? ;D ). However, my second test returns red, with a rather peculiar message:

```
Placing an ad
  (1) The ad token should match across domains
  (2) can go places (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Placing an ad (2) can go places
     Failure/Error: visit "/"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

What I'm working on is some cross-domain JS. I need to verify that my JS in another domain matches an attribute of a model in my actual Rails app. I got the first part to work, where I  leave my app to go to the other domain, but the second part blows up in my face, when I'm returning the app_host to the original location.

How I should I modify my code to accomplish my intention?